# Facebook Graph API and Action Links

Tags: ruby, facebook

I'm trying to replicate Facebook action links with the Open Graph API.  I have the following snippet:

```
HTTParty.post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed", query: { message: "...", picture: "...", access_token: "...", actions: [{ link: "http://google.com", name: "Example" }] })
```

However it is returning (and I'm not sure why):

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#100) The post's action links must be valid URLs."}}
```

Anyone have any experience with action links using the graph API?

Comment: Maybe try URL encoding? or for some reason leaving www out of http://google.com may cause issues

Comment: @DSchultz Tried adding the 'www' (no luck). How do I URL encode it?

Comment: url_encoded_string = CGI::escape("http://www.google.com")

Comment: You can also check the output from our [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) generator which does the same thing to your source URL

Comment: @DShultz Escaping the URL didn't help (same error) and the generator doesn't seem to escape the URL at all for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, I assume you've tried other domains than google?

Comment: @DShultz Yes, I've tried a bunch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the actions array should be JSON encoded, HTTParty might not do this automatically / correctly. Try

```
HTTParty.post(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed",
    :query => {
        :message => "...",
        :picture => "...",
        :access_token => "...",
        :actions => [{ link: "http://google.com", name: "Example" }].to_json
    }
)
```

(Assuming you have a library included that provides Array#to_json…)

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem.